# Active databases, hierarchical structure, write a set of triggers

Tags: sql, triggers, eventtrigger

Direct connections between locations are represented in a

- Table `DirectConn` (IdSource, Id Target, Distance)
- Table `BestConn` (IdSource, Id Target, MinDistance)

describes the minimum distance associated with the direct or multi-hop paths connecting each pair of (reachable) locations.

Write a set of triggers that react to insertions into `DirectConn` and update the `BestConn` table if needed.

This is the text of a past exam from my university. I really have no idea how to go about creating a working set of triggers.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

This is a solution i have tried

```
CREATE TRIGGER
AFTER INSERT ON DirectConn
for each row
BEGIN
INSERT INTO BestConn new values(new.IdSource, new.IdTarget
(select Distance
from DirectConn
where not exists (SELECT *
                  FROM BestConn
                  WHERE MinDistance = new.Distance AND IdSource = new.IdSource AND IdTarget = new.IdTarget)

DELETE FROM BestConn
WHERE IdSource = new.IdSource AND IdTarget = new.IdTarget

INSERT INTO BestConn new values(
SELECT D2.IdSource, D.IdTarget, sum(Distance)
FROM DirectConn D JOIN DirectConn D2
WHERE new.IdSource = D.IdTarget AND new.IdTarget = D2.IdSource)
END;
```

Comment: make a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/ and add tables and data and then test your approch, the error messages generate help to find the error. also most specific  udes that exist for your database help also. btw. the image is unreadable, please don't post inages

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean ... but a picture of hand written code is a new one. As nbk said, reproducibility is the name of the game to get good answers.

Comment: When you say you “have no idea how to go about creating a working set of triggers”, presumably you do know how to create triggers, so you could at least make a start and update your question with the attempt?

Comment: @NickW
Sorry for the image, it's my first time on this forum. I edited the message with the code too